# WPF TreeViewItem Expanding Animation

Tags: wpf, animation, expand

I used the code from question [Wpf treeview - i want to animate the expansion of the nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454716), but the animation doesn't work on the first expand, it does work for the consequent expand events.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Trigger Value to false
and swap the EnterAction's storyboard to ExitAction's

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
        <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="light"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource grau80}"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="Timeline1">
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost" Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.4">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="Timeline2">
                           <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost" Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                           <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                           <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Grid>
                          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Style="{DynamicResource TB_Tree}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press"/>
                          <Border Name="Bd" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0.8" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="2,0"/>
                          </Border>
                              <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0">
                                 <ItemsPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                  <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0" />
                                 </ItemsPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                </ItemsPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true"> 
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Timeline1}"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Timeline2}"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="HasHeader" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Header" Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="HasHeader" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Header" Property="MinHeight" Value="19"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Orange}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource weiss}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Orange}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource weiss}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource grau60}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource weiss}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                      </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
```